# POST s3 presigned url call in postman returns SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, postman

When calling a presigned POST endpoint returned from my node.js server I receive what looks like a valid response:

[image: GET presigned url]
Note I am setting environment variables to make the POST call easier to repeat.

When calling the presigned URL however I receive a 403 response with SignatureDoesNotMatch error code. I am having a lot of difficulty finding resources about using the POST presigned url. So my questions are as follows:

1. Am I calling the presigned URL correctly (see below)?
2. How can I debug to understand what is happening here (I've tried turning on the bucket logs, but nothing is logged)?
3. What might I look at further to resolve this issue?

When performing the post it is my understanding that the call is to POST to the url returned and using form-data include all "fields" in the body with the final key being labelled as file with the file to be uploaded attached. From the above response I have therefore used the following call in postman:
Headers:
[image: POST presigned url Headers]

Body (I have tried both with and without Content-Type included):
[image: body]

However when I make this call I receive a 403 forbidden response and a SignatureDoesNotMatch error code:
[image: 403 response]

Here is the code to generate the presigned URL (using "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.25.0",
"@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post": "^3.25.0" within package.json):

```
const { createPresignedPost } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post");
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const s3 = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  region: "eu-west-2",
});
async function getSignedUrl() {

  const params = {
    Bucket: "richbits-test",
    Key: "d3c0c9a0-ff91-11eb-bbe6-b9d90cd8bb8f",
    Conditions: [["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"]],
  };

  console.log(params);

  const signedUrl = await createPresignedPost(s3, params);

  return signedUrl;
}
```

I've double checked the bucket and keys, but would appreciate some advice as to how I might move forward or any useful resources which can help me understand the use of these presigned urls better please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Woah, the documentation from AWS on these headers is terrible. Here is what I figured out.

1. The output of `createPresignedPost()` is an object with two keys: `url` and `fields`. The `fields` object contains all the form fields and respective values that you must use when submitting the post. You would copy these fields and only these fields to your Postman request.
2. There are a few fields that the AWS SDK will add automatically, including `bucket`, `key`, `policy`, and several fields required to generate the signature. With the JavaScript SDK, these were `X-Amz-Algorithm`, `X-Amz-Credential`, `X-Amz-Date`, and `X-Amz-Signature` (though for the Python SDK, these were `AWSAccessKeyId` and `signature`). These will be returned in the `fields` key from `createPresignedPost()`, so you do not need to manually generate them.
3. The `Fields` parameter of `createPresignedPost()` is for additional fields that you want to add to the form. The entire set of fields that could possibly be added is listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html#sigv4-HTTPPOSTFormFields). However, the SDK handles many of these for you, particularly the required ones. According to the [Python SDK docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.generate_presigned_post), the fields that you could include in `Fields` are `acl`, `Cache-Control`, `Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition`, `Content-Encoding`, `Expires`, `success_action_redirect`, `redirect`, `success_action_status`, and `x-amz-meta-`.
4. The `Fields` and `Conditions` parameters of `createPresignedPost()` need to be synchronized such that any field in `Fields` also has a condition in `Conditions` and vice versa.

Putting this altogether, I believe the problem with your `getSignedUrl()` function was that it was missing a `Fields` parameter for `createPresignedPost()` that had a key-value pair for `Content-Type` (since you have a condition for `Content-Type`). Without the `Content-Type` in the `Fields` parameter, the calculated signature would not include the `Content-Type` field. If you then left out the `Content-Type` field your signature might match, but your policy conditions would fail because it required `Content-Type` to be present and equal to `image/jpeg`. If you included `Content-Type`, then your signature would not match.

Here is could that should work for you.

```js
const { createPresignedPost } = require("@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post");
const { S3Client } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const s3 = new S3Client({
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
  },
  signatureVersion: "v4",
  region: "eu-west-2",
});
async function getSignedUrl() {

  const params = {
    Bucket: "richbits-test",
    Key: "d3c0c9a0-ff91-11eb-bbe6-b9d90cd8bb8f",
    Conditions: [["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"]],
    Fields: {"Content-Type": "image/jpeg"},
  };

  console.log(params);

  const signedUrl = await createPresignedPost(s3, params);

  return signedUrl;
}
getSignedUrl().then(res => {
        console.log(res)
})
```

The output of this should be

```
{
  Bucket: 'richbits-test',
  Key: 'd3c0c9a0-ff91-11eb-bbe6-b9d90cd8bb8f',
  Conditions: [ [ 'eq', '$Content-Type', 'image/jpeg' ] ],
  Fields: { 'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg' }
}
{
  url: 'https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/richbits-test',
  fields: {
    'Content-Type': 'image/jpeg',
    bucket: 'richbits-test',
    'X-Amz-Algorithm': 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256',
    'X-Amz-Credential': '<YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID>/20211005/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request',
    'X-Amz-Date': '20211005T111446Z',
    key: 'd3c0c9a0-ff91-11eb-bbe6-b9d90cd8bb8f',
    Policy: '<SOME_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING>',
    'X-Amz-Signature': '<THE_SIGNATURE>'
  }
}
```

Then your POST request would include the form fields `Content-Type`, `bucket`, `X-Amz-Algorithm`, `X-Amz-Credential`, `X-Amz-Date`, `Policy`, and `X-Amz-Signature`. Here is what an HTML form would look like.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>

  <form action="https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/richbits-test" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Bucket:
    <input type="input" name="bucket" value="richbits-test" /><br />
    Key to upload: 
    <input type="input"  name="key" value="d3c0c9a0-ff91-11eb-bbe6-b9d90cd8bb8f" /><br />
    Content-Type: 
    <input type="input"  name="Content-Type" value="image/jpeg" /><br />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Credential" value="<YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID>/20211005/eu-west-2/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="text"   name="X-Amz-Date" value="20211005T111446Z" />

    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="<SOME_BASE64_ENCODED_STRING>" />'
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<THE_SIGNATURE>" />
    
    File: 
    <input type="file"   name="file" /> <br />
    <!-- The elements after this will be ignored -->
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload to Amazon S3" />
  </form>
  
</html>
```

As far as debugging this issue, I did not find anything useful from the `POST` request to S3. I either got no response or an unauthorized status, without any indication what the problem was.

Comment: Many thanks I appreciate you taking the time to respond. I've tried your suggested changes and still get the same result. I tried with postman and also tried with the form you provided. In the former I still get SignatureDoesNotMatch and the latter Access Denied error. There is more I can do to review why there is a difference between the two attempts, but for now I'm still no wiser about what might be going on.

Comment: @Richbits, when you received the SignatureDoesNotMatch error, did you add a `Fields` parameter for `createPresignedPost()` and also include the `Content-Type` in the body of your request in Postman? Are you sure your Postman environment variables are working properly?

Comment: Yes, I'm passing this:   const params = {
    Bucket: "richbits-test",
    Key: "d3c0c9a0-ff91-11eb-bbe6-b9d90cd8bb8f",
    Conditions: [["eq", "$Content-Type", "image/jpg"]],
    Fields: { "Content-Type": "image/jpg" },
  }; and included content type in the body. I also used the page that you posted above and set up a new user and double checked the creds. I've no idea now, I'm going to try with a put which should atleast validate that I am using the creds correctly.

Comment: @Richbits, I also tried the request using Postman and it worked using the settings you have in your images. I did notice that your Postman request had the "Content-Type" field set to "image/jpeg" and your comment said that your `params` for `createPresignedPost` included `Fields: {"Content-Type": "image/jpg"}`. I'm not sure if this was a typo, but these two should match; they should both be `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Yes, I think I was trying with image/jpg, as that matches the extension, but I've since reviewed and know it is not a valid mime type. I've reviewed from scratch and found that in Postman after the Policy variable there was a space, so that probably explains why it was not working there. The HTML form is also working, so I suspect that in my original there was another errant space or something similar. Thanks for your help, I'll accept your answer.